# API-gateway multiple identity sources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to set up an authorizer with API-gateway, I want it to get triggered when `foo` header is passed in or when `bar` header is passed in.

Right now from the documentation it seems like if I specify both `foo` and `bar` as identity sources, both needs to be present.

The only workaround for this which I found is to use no identity sources but then we are not able to use caching since identidy sources are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced the same problem and come to the same conclusion.

If you want to have multiple headers as identity sources for a lambda authorizer, both must be present for all requests.

From the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/configure-api-gateway-lambda-authorization-with-console.html):

> API Gateway uses the specified identity sources as the request authorizer caching key. When caching is enabled, API Gateway calls the authorizer's Lambda function only after successfully verifying that **all the specified identity sources are present at runtime**. If a specified identify source is missing, null, or empty, API Gateway returns a 401 Unauthorized response without calling the authorizer Lambda function.

Unfortunately this means that if you want to allow different individual headers for a lambda authorizer, you are unable to use caching.